# One Domain, One publish IP, Multiple servers

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, nginx, ip

Apologies in advance for being a total newbie with all things infrastructure related.

A little background: I'm developing a server app for an Android application. The app will communicate with the backend using its domain name (for instance, JSON POST example.com/doSomething). The server code is currently running behind nginx on one machine and everything works fine.

I only have 1 external IP address (which is where example.com is directed to).

However, I have 2 Linux servers at my disposal which I would like to use to host the server. They will host identical binaries and have access to the same database, etc. and will behave identically in all respects. I would like to use both servers so that I can have (1) redundancy and (2) performance optimization (round robin) if possible instead of the current setup which is 1 server behind my domain.

The question is: Is it possible to somehow configure nginx (or anything else really, even the DNS server) so that requests to example.com automatically are redirected to one of the two servers, whilst maintaining a round robin structure, so that both servers serve the same number of requests and if one server goes down, the requests still get sent to the second server?

If it's possible, how would I go about it and if not, do you know of any other way to make use of both servers?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with `nginx`, but I'd recommend [haproxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) to do your loadbalancing.

You will want to run it on both your nodes, with a [floating IP](http://www.keepalived.org/) to implement redundancy for your load balancing service (i.e., make sure that the loadbalancer doesn't become your Single Point of Failure).

Comment: Thank you very much Felix. I have to use nginx for my use-case because of the limitation of the underlying framework I'm using (and my lack of understanding of other technologies doing this). With regards to "floating IP" or KeepAlived link you pasted, I had a quick look and it looks to be exactly what I need. One question though, does the Virtual host live as a daemon on BOTH servers? If not (i.e. it only runs on one server), how would it prevent the single point of failure issue? Wouldn't it become a SPOF itself?

Comment: Note that you can operate haproxy as a proxy in front of nginx. That's my recommendation. - What do you mean by "virtual host"?

Comment: I looked at http://www.keepalived.org/pdf/UserGuide.pdf and there, it mentions an  "LVS Router" (or a Linux Virtual Server) which I referred to as Virtual Host (my bad). It's a daemon process that I need to run apparently to activate the KeppAlived to assign virtual IPS to my nodes. That's what I was referring to. I'll definitely look at the haproxy on nginx tonight.

Comment: Keepalived runs on each node to make them a redundant pair. For your use case, the VRRP support would suffice, no need to go for LVS.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will have a look at these soon. Marked as answer.